# Why does this function throw an error when using the includes method?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out why this function throws an error when it reaches the `'includes'` method, when console logging whitelist, it shows that it is an array, when i use the includes method, it is throwing an error, `cannot read property includes of undefined`

```
const test = (body, ...whitelists) => {
  const bodies = whitelists.map(({ type = null, whitelist }) => {
    console.log('whitelist ', whitelist)

    const whitelistedBody = Object.entries(body).reduce(
      (newBody, [key, value]) => {
        console.log('KEY ', key)
        console.log('whitelist ', whitelists)

        if (whitelist.includes(key)) {
          newBody[key] = value;
        }

        console.log('newBody ', newBody)
        return newBody;
      },
      {}
    );

    return { type, body: whitelistedBody };
  });

  return (
    bodies.find(({ body }) => Object.keys(body).length) || {
      body: {},
      type: null,
    }
  );
};

test({firstKey: '123'}, ['firstKey']);
```

Comment: do you mean `whitelist.includes`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are passing an array as second parameter of `test`, then you try to extract a `whitelist` property from this array, which makes no sense.

The `console.log('whitelist ', whitelist)` shows `undefined` as expected, because `['firstKey'].whitelist` is `undefined`.

Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

1) set default = []

```
  const bodies = whitelists.map(({ type = null, whitelist = [] }) => {
```

or

2) replaced whitelist to whitelists

```
if (whitelists.includes(key)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed, its actually my fault, I mistakenly passed in an array for the 2nd argument of the function call, where it should be an object.  Also, includes should've been called on whitelist and not whitelists.

In actuality it looks like `test({firstKey:'123'}, {whitelist: ['firstKey']})`